# Can userspace code leverage NVIDIA's open-sourcing of their kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, cuda, nvidia, cuda-driver

NVIDIA has recently [announced](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-releases-open-source-gpu-kernel-modules/) they are open-sourcing (a variant of) their GPU Linux kernel driver. They are not, however, open-sourcing the user-mode driver libraries (e.g. `libcuda.so`).

It's a gradual process and not all GPUs are supported initially, but regardless of these details: Is there some way that developers of user-space code can leverage this open-sourcing? Or is it only interesting/useful for kernel developers?

What I would personally love to be able to do is avoid having to make libcuda calls to get the current context. If that piece of information were somehow readable now from userspace, that could be neat. Of course that's just wishful thinking on my part - I don't know how to check what the driver directly "exposes" - if anything.

Comment: According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia-open-kernel&num=1), the benefits for developers is "better tracing/debugging and better integration around customized versions of the Linux kernel". Also note that "OpenGL / Vulkan / OpenCL / CUDA drivers remain closed-source" which is the part you should interact as a user-land developer so I do not think it will change much from your pov. At least not much more than for end-users. I am wondering if low-level profiling could be improved with that.